# Solving an ODE system which depends on a periodic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following ODE system and want to show that all solutions $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(z))$ exist for all times (or can be extended on all of $\mathbb{R}$). The only problem is that the system depends on an unknown function $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, which is smooth, positive and periodic.

\begin{align*}
\ddot{x}(t)&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{c'(z(t))}{c(z(t))}\dot{y}(t)^2 \\
\ddot{y}(t)&=-\frac{c'(z(t))}{c(z(t))}\dot{y}(t)\dot{z}(t)\\
\ddot{z}(t)&=-\frac{c'(z(t))}{c(z(t))}\dot{z}(t)^2.
\end{align*}

I can rewrite the last equation to get  $c(z)\ddot{z}+c'(z)\dot{z}^2=0$, so $\frac{d}{dt}(\dot{z}c(z))=0$, which tells me that $\dot{z(t)}c(z(t))=a_1$ for some constant $a_1\neq 0$. Solving this gives the implicit expression
\begin{align*}
a_1 t+a_2=\int_{a_3}^{z(t)}c(\xi)d\xi
\end{align*}
for $a_2,a_3$ constants. Substituting $\dot{z}=\frac{a_1}{c(z)}$ in the second equation I get $\ddot{y}=-a_1\frac{c'(z)}{c(z)^2}\dot{y}$ which can also be written as $\ddot{y}=\frac{\ddot{z}}{\dot{z}}\dot{y}$. Now I don't know how to continue. I'm pretty sure one cannot proceed solving this without knowing what the function $c$ is. But since $c$ is periodic (so in particular $c$ and $c'$ are bounded) I have hope that one nevertheless can show that all solutions exist for all time.

Comment: You can find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but this is too long to fit into a comment.

Write the second equation as

$$ \frac{\ddot y}{\dot y} = \frac{\ddot z}{\dot z} $$

and integrate both sides to get

$$ \ln \dot y = \ln \dot z + \ln b_0 \implies \dot y = b_0\dot z \implies y(t) = b_0z(t) + b_1 $$

where $b_0$, $b_1$ are arbitrary constants to be determined by initial conditions

The first equation is

$$ \ddot x = -\frac12 \frac{\ddot z}{\dot z^2}\dot y^2 = -\frac{b_0^2}{2}\ddot z \implies x(t) = -\frac{b_0^2}{2}z(t) + b_2t + b_3 $$

If you can show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $z$ and $t$, then the solution exists.

Comment: What do you mean by a one-to-one correspondence between $z(t)$ and $t$? And can I say that $z(t)$ is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ by the above implicit expression (by using the properties of $c$)? If so, wouldn't this immediately imply (by your computation) that also $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I mean that a value of $z$ can be found for every value of $t$ (i.e. the function $t(z)$ is one-to-one on its domain). If you've already shown this, then the problem is finished

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why my problem would be solved if I knew that there is a 1:1 correspondence between $t$ and $z(t)$. Maybe you could explain this in the following example: Let's take  $c(\xi)=\cos(\xi)+2$ (which is positive, smooth and periodic). Then if we choose $a_2,a_3=0$ the implicit expression becomes  $a_1t=\sin(z(t))+2z(t)$. I'm not even sure what I can say in this specific case about the existence of $z(t)$ (does it exist for all times or can we only define it locally and then extend the solution?)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you can express $z(t)$ in closed form. The answer can always be found numerically. Given a value of $t$, you can find a corresponding value of $z$ because there is a one-to-one relationship. All you need to know is that $z(t)$ exists and isn't multi-valued.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't the assumption that $c$ is periodic already tell me that $z(t)$ can't be injective (so $t(z)$ will be multi valued), because $\dot{z}=\frac{a_1}{c(z)}$?

Comment: No, periodicity doesn't guarantee one-to-one. Take, for example, $c(z) = \cos (z)$, then $t(z) = \sin (z)$ up to an additive constant, which of course isn't one-to-one.

Comment: No, what I meant is that periodicity implies that one $\textbf{never}$ gets injectivity in this case (because of the way $\dot{z}$ is defined).

Comment: That's not true either. Take $c(z)=2+\cos z$, then $t(z) = 2z + \sin z$ is injective over $\Bbb R$

Comment: Ok I see. Since $c$ is also assumed to be positive, do you think it would be possible to show that $t(z)$ is always injective?

Comment: Why can you always write the second equation as $\frac{\ddot{y}}{\dot{y}}=\frac{\ddot{z}}{\dot{z}}$? What if $\dot{y}$ has zeroes? Then the expression is not even defined. Or is this an assumption you're making?

Comment: We can consider $\dot y = \dot z = 0$ as a special case, then when $\dot y \ne 0$ that is the solution

Comment: A different way is to write $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\dot y}{\dot z} = \frac{\ddot y \dot z - \dot y \ddot z}{\dot z^2} = 0$$